# .NET 4.72 reference .NET Standard 2.0 Project Dependencies

Tags: c#, .net-standard

I have a .NET 4.72 project. I want to reference an assembly from .NET Standard 2.0 using nuGet. When I try to add the reference, I asked to install about 20 other packages. Is there a way I can skip adding these dependencies?

[image]

Here is my project:

[image]

Comment: The package *depends* on those dependencies. You shouldn't worry about them though, only the root package is added to the project files. The other packages are resolved when you restore/build your application. They don't even appear as direct dependencies when you add the package to your project

Comment: If A needs B to work, then how would the project (nuget) package you trying to ref work without the reference dependencies....?, its like if you had two class libs and the A had a reference to B, someone wanted to use you lib but you only gave them A, would it work. The answer is no so, in order for the package you want to work, it will need its dependencies.